# Splitting integers 8 --> [1,7],[2,6]

Tags: python-3.x

---

I'm looking to make a function where I take an integer greater than 3 and show different ways you can add the number. For example 6 would turn into [[1,5],[2,4]] and not including [3,3]. 3 would turn into [[1,2]]. 8 would turn into [[1,7],[2,6],[3,5]] and not including [4,4]

My attempt thus far.

```
 def split(k):
    values = []
    for i in range(k//2):
        values.append([i+1,k-1-i])
    print(values)
```

Running into issues where it is showing the [3,3] and [4,4]. Not sure about the logic behind this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `math.ceil` to account for odd numbers and just round up after float division.

```
from math import ceil

def split(k):
    return [[i, k-i] for i in range(1, ceil(k/2))]
```

So in the case of 9, range will generate values 1 - 5 excluding 5, `1, 2, 3, 4` and then just subtract those from 9 to form the pairs.

You can also provide range a start value of `1` to ignore zeros.

```
# Output
>>> split(3)
[[1, 2]]
>>> split(8)
[[1, 7], [2, 6], [3, 5]]
>>> split(9)
[[1, 8], [2, 7], [3, 6], [4, 5]]
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know about the ceiling function. Really helpful.

Comment: No worries, you could also just do `range(1, (k + 1) // 2)` which has the same effect.